# How to get a custom cell property index path in another class in objective c language

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a custom cell it contains a label and a button. this XIB is registered in another tableview class. Now i need to know index path of the button to insert another row in tableview when i click the button.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: you can add the indexPath as property and set it in the cellForRow method

Comment: Like this? in cellFor RowAtIndexPath{ cell.buttonIndexPath = indexpath; }

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
- (void)btnAction:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;

    id vwSuperView = sender;

    while (![vwSuperView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
    {
        vwSuperView = [vwSuperView superview];
    }

    indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[(UITableViewCell *)vwSuperView center]];
}
```